# GDM Crashed after upgrading Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gdm

OS : Arch Linux.
This happened 3 weeks ago i updated my system `sudo pacman -Syu` then after reboot GDM Crashed and tried reinstalling GDM using live usb, magically worked, yesterday happened again i tried doing what i did last time but i got different situation :

- GDM started but not showing any network options ( i already installed NetworkManager and enable it and other network-related packages but nothing changed).
- Screen wont turn on unless unplugging all all connected usb devices such as keyboard,usb stick,...

Does anyone have an idea about howa to fix it? And how to prevent it from happening in future?

Answer (score 0):

If you get to `grub`, press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit the launch options and add a `3` at the end of the line that starts with `linux`. This way, you'll get into TTY-mode (**the changes are *not* persistent, i.e. the settings do not remain across system boots**). From there, you can start to try recovering the system. If this is successful, see the steps below.

---

Option one:

```
sudo pacman -Sgq gnome                     # lists all the packages that in the group
sudo pacman -Sgq gnome | sudo pacman -Rs - # will remove everything in the group, recursively
```

**Be careful** as this will remove **everything** and you may end up without networking etc.

This being said, a *safer* way would be to install another desktop environment, e.g. Plasma and then try to manually recover GNOME through that one.

---

Option two:

```
sudo pacman -Sgq gnome                     # lists all the packages that in the group
sudo pacman -Sgq gnome | sudo pacman -Rs - # will remove everything in the group, recursively
sudo reboot                                # reboots the system

### REMEMBER TO REPEAT THE STEPS (GRUB) IN THE FIRST PARAGRAPH OF THE POST

sudo pacman -Syu                           # updates the system
sudo reboot                                

### REMEMBER TO REPEAT THE STEPS (GRUB) IN THE FIRST PARAGRAPH OF THE POST

sudo pacman -S xorg xorg-server            # installs the windowing systems
sudo pacman -S gnome                       # installs the gnome de
sudo systemctl enable gdm.service          # enables the display server
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I tried installing lightdm but it won't start or show anything. Something else, gdm is not detecting my second screen.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "won't start or show anything" part?